# Parsing model fields in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a simple Django model with a DateTime field that I'm building into the Django REST Framework. Django saves the DateTime fields in a format that resembles `2014-12-07T17:00:00Z`. Is it possible to parse this field in the serializer so when I pull in the API response it's already in the proper format?

```
# SERIALIZER
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Events
            depth = 1 

# VIEW
class EventViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Events.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EventSerializer

# MODEL
class Events(models.Model):
    title    = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    content  = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    date     = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Locations, related_name='events')

    def __unicode__(self):
       return unicode(self.title)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'events'
```

Comment: DateTime data is DateTime data. Why do you want to change the format?  If you are going to be showing it in the template, there are different Template Tags / args you can use to do it there.

Comment: What format are you looking for?

Comment: This is clearly documented [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#datetimefield) Simply define your datetime field with the proper `format` argument..